# difference between $|x^{p}|$ and $|x|^{p}$ when $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, radicals

Is there any difference between $|x^{p}|$ and $|x|^{p}$ when $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., set of real numbers in terms of continuity and differentiablity. In measure theory I have to show they are covex, i. e., second derivative greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: There is a difference between them if you allow $p$ to be a non-integer. For example when $p=\dfrac12,$ first function is ill defined on negative reals while the second function is well defined every where.

Comment: Note $|x|^p$ is convex only if $p \ge 1$.

Comment: @Bumblebee hmm, but $|(-2)^{1/2}| = |\pm \sqrt2 i| = \sqrt2 = |{-2}|^{1/2}$. In general $|x^p| = |\exp(p \log |x| + 2k\pi ip)| = \exp(p \log |x| )=|x|^p$...so somehow life is well